# Upload image from local system + TinyMCE editor + ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, image-uploading

i am using tinymce editor to upload cms content from backend but it allows image to be uploaded only by using external links  but i want to upload image from my local system.

i'll greatly appreciate your help for solving my problem..... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

You could base64-encode the image and put it in your editor. In this case you would not need to care about links.